# How do I query in mysql for path to leaf node back to root node

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list, hierarchical-trees

Suppose I have this table:

[image: A hierarchical table]

Now if I need to get the path to the root node from any node , how will I get that ?

Suppose I have searched for id=28, then I want to get (0,19,20) path to root node by parent_id.

**Update on Abhik Chakraborty's comment:
Please note that , I am not asking for any hierarchical query.**

**Update on Shadow's Comment : 
I cannot use procedure that's why I asked for help on query. Please don't answer any stored procedure.**

Comment: MySql does not have any hierarchical query, you may do this on application level using recursive function.

Comment: The 1st duplicate link provides you a non-recursive MySQL procedure as a solution, the 2nd duplicate link provides you with more of a theoretical background and lists some alternatives to storing your hierarchical data in an adjacency list format. Verdict is: this is going to be ugly in your current data model.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why this data model is going to be ugly and what will be the better approach. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks